# Integrating vuestorefront in magento 2

Tags: magento2, integration, front

I am integrating vuestorefront with magento 2. While running **yarn installer** it's throw below error. if anyone has come this error, Please reply.[image]

Comment: make sure your tokens are valid.

Comment: yes tokens are valid